# Table-Valued Function (TVF) uses a lot of Temp DB disk space

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I converted an old table-valued function that was using views and scalar functions to a new stored procedure, now it's taking less than 10 seconds to return data instead of forever processing until Temp DB gets full. Why was the TVF behaving this way? Any ideas?

Comment: Far too broad a question without code and without execution plans. And generally speaking - you check the execution plan to evaluate performance. Perhaps the old code was just poorly written? Impossible to say without specific information.

Comment: 1) views on views == bad, (2) scalar UDF's can't go parallel, other than that, question is far too broad.

Comment: With the minuscule amount of information you've provided, you're probably not going to get a concrete answer. But I'll hazard a guess: It's possible the TVF was being called against every row in the data set. That would be one way a TVF could use lots of tempdb and have terrible performance.

Comment: @MitchWheat is right, but the good news is it's fixed and you've learned how poor views, nested views, and scalar functions can be

Comment: Thanks guys for your input, I will be checking some more old TVFs to avoid such pain in future. For curiosity's sake, this is what was happening:

Comment: `FUNCTION [dbo].[CURRENT_TVF](@ID uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
 RETURN
 SELECT *
 FROM [VIEW_A]
 JOIN ANOTHER_TVF(SCALAR_VALUED_FUNC(@ID))
 ON  LocationId = ptrLocationId
 WHERE id = @ID 
 OR @ID = SCALAR_VALUED_FUNC()
`
--Points to note: 
1. View_A was using another VIEW together with 2 inline Scalar-valued functions 
2. ANOTHER_TVF was also using 1 Scalar-valued function

Comment: You almost couldn't write that query to be slower to be honest. If you weren't a new contributor, I'd think you were playing a joke on us. I'm happy that you have fixed this.